# strange slowdown after maven completes

Tags: maven

I have a java project that takes up to 10 seconds to shut down after maven does its thing. Even doing a simple mvn clean takes more than 10 seconds. It seems to be just hanging.

```
$ time mvn clean
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for io.inbot:inbot-java:jar:1.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 35, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin is missing. @ line 45, column 12
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin is missing. @ line 31, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin is missing. @ line 144, column 21
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building inbot-java 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ inbot-java ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/jilles/git/linko/inbot-java/target
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.373 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-08-20T12:42:13+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/1963M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[1]+  Done                    mvn clean

real    0m12.603s
user    0m14.689s
sys 0m0.303s
```

I've tried sending a kill -QUIT to the process to see what it is actually doing but it appears to no longer be able to dump a stacktrace during the time it hangs. That means probably some shutdown hook or finalization is still running but the vm is no longer responding.

I'm using this maven version:

```
mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T13:57:37+02:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_31, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

with this environment

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home
MAVEN_OPTS='-Xms2048M -Xmx2048M'
```

The full commandline reported by ps -h

```
24547 ttys000    0:05.57 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xms2048M -Xmx2048M -classpath /usr/local/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar -Dclassworlds.conf=/usr/local/maven/bin/m2.conf -Dmaven.home=/usr/local/maven -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=/Users/jilles/git/linko/inbot-java org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher clean
```

I'd love to know what is going on or even better how to fix it.

**Edit: found the root cause: ch.raffael.doclets.pegdown.PegdownDoclet; see answer below**

Comment: can you try this offline to see if Maven is hanging on a http request for any reason?

Comment: adding -o does not seem to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Did the obvious thing and finally determined that a doclet we use for the javadoc plugin is the root cause. As soon as I comment this, the problem goes away. This leaves the question why this even activates at all on a mvn clean.

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <doclet>ch.raffael.doclets.pegdown.PegdownDoclet</doclet>
                    <docletArtifact>
                        <groupId>ch.raffael.pegdown-doclet</groupId>
                        <artifactId>pegdown-doclet</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1</version>
                    </docletArtifact>
                    <useStandardDocletOptions>true</useStandardDocletOptions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: IIRC, it should depend on which goals (or phases, can't remember actually) that plugin is configured to attach to. I can't help you further on this, though.